# compile a c# dynamically created source for net.core from vb.net 4.5 framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-core

I've got a vb.net project running into .net 4.5.2 that creates a c# source I'd like to build to run in core 2.0 environment. I use CodeDom as follows:

```
Public Function Compila(sourceName As String, Source As String) As Boolean

    Dim provider As CodeDomProvider = Nothing
    Dim compileOk As Boolean = True
    Dim path As String = getSetting("EP").ToString

    provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")

    Dim exeName As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}.dll", path, sourceName.Replace(".", "_"))
    Dim cp As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters()

    cp.GenerateExecutable = False ' Generate an executable instead of a class library.
    cp.OutputAssembly = exeName ' Specify the assembly file name to generate.
    cp.GenerateInMemory = False ' Save the assembly as a physical file.
    cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False ' Set whether to treat all warnings as errors.

    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Configuration.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Newtonsoft.Json.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MongoDB.Bson.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MongoDB.Driver.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll")
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("log4net.dll")

    ' Invoke compilation of the source file.
    Dim cr As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, Source)

    If cr.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        compileOk = False
        ' Display compilation errors.
        Dim errori As String = ""
        Dim ce As CompilerError
        For Each ce In cr.Errors
            errori += ce.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
        Next ce
        MessageBox.Show(errori)
    Else
        ' Display a successful compilation message.
        MessageBox.Show(sourceName + ".dll created in " + path)
    End If

    Return compileOk

End Function
```

I receive an

> CS0012 Error: The type ‘System.Object’ is defined in an assembly that
>   is not reference. Add reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=
>   4.2.0.0....

and more.

Comment: the error is telling you that you have a lower version of the assembly than the one set for the project using 4.5.2

Comment: I've got installed the 4.3.0 version of System.Runtime...

Comment: well this is probably your issue.. either roll back the project to .net 4.3.x or up it to 4.5.x

Comment: I've tryed to roll back to .net 4 and then to up it to .net 7. Always the same error...

Comment: @AgoMar I feel like you need to clarify your most recent statement: `I've tryed to roll back to .net 4 and then to up it to .net 7.` There is not .NET version 7.

Comment: @JamieTaylor sorry I mean 4.7...

Comment: Ok. I would stay clear of .NET Framework 4.7 if you want to consume the code with .NET Core. Version 2.0 of the .NET Standard is implemented by .NET Core 2.0 and /NET Framework 4.6.1 (thus 4.7 is not supported). See this link for more info on .NET Standard versions https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md